# how to disable the GotFocus on textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, textbox, focus

I have a `textbox` that does something on `GotFocus`.

How can I disable the `GotFocus` event on this `textbox`?

How to enable it back?

Sorry, I forgot -  i work on Windows-mobile 6.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else? Also, your question is unclear: Why don't you simply get rid of your GotFocus handler?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot -  i work on Windows-mobile 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always Enable or Disable the control as well

```
void ButtonEnabled(bool value) {
   textBox1.Enabled = value;
}
```

The code above is much too short to write a routine for, but gets the point across easier.

Answer (score 1):

May be `TextBox.CanFocus = false;` and then `CanFocus = true;` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use **WPF**, `TesxBox.Focusable` property should be used.
`TesxBox.Focusable = true` enables you to got focus. `TesxBox.Focusable = false` - disables you to got focus